# Text is not fitting the column

Tags: tables, line-breaking

I want my texts to continue in the next line instead of continuing in the other column. How can I manage this? My code is :
![enter image description here][1]

```
\begin{tabular}{|p{2,8cm}|p{2.8cm}|p{2.8cm}|p{2.8cm}|p{2.8cm}|}
  \hline
  \textbf{Architecture }& \textbf{Sharing }& \textbf{TrustSetting} & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{\textbf{Access Control}}\\ \hline
  Distributed:\cite{ 40crossdomain},\cite{51cassandra},\cite{53oasis},\cite{54huDynamic},\cite{79searchengine},\cite{19paas} &    & Trusted: & \textbf{Cryptographic }& \textbf{Non-cryptographic} \\ \cline{4-5}
    &   &  &  &  \\ 
   &    &  &  & \\\cline{1-1}\cline{3-4}
  Centralized: &    & Semi-trusted: &  &  \\\cline{2-2}
   &    &  & &  \\ 
   &   &  &  &  \\\cline{1-1}\cline{3-4}
  Cloud: &    & Untrusted: &  & \\
   &   & &   &   \\ \hline

\end{tabular}
```

Comment: you can use the `{}` button in the editor to mark code sections (see my edit) generally we prefer complete documents so people can test answers. You may find it sufficient to put a space after the `,` which is the common practice and allows some flexibility and line breaking

Comment: What happens if you insert a space between `Distributed:` and `\cite{ 40crossdomain}`?

Comment: Shouldn't 2,8cm be 2.8cm (decimal vs comma)?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle did this post look like that when you commented? It looks mighty weird to me like most of the code is missing. Has the last edit done something odd to the question?

Comment: @Mico see above to David

Comment: @FionaSmith I rolled back the edits

Comment: @FionaSmith - My comment was based on the temporarily "hidden" screen shot and associated image. I still think that inserting a space after `Distributed` would help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you insert a space between `Distributed:` and the series of `\cite` commands, you'll allow LaTeX to insert a line break. The `?` marks in the screenshot below arise because I can't resolve the `\cite` instructions. If need be, insert another space between some of the `\cite` commands in order to allow still another line break.

![enter image description here][1]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tabular}{|p{2.8cm}|p{2.8cm}|p{2.8cm}|p{2.8cm}|p{2.8cm}|}
\hline
\textbf{Architecture }& \textbf{Sharing }& \textbf{TrustSetting} & 
\multicolumn{2}{l|}{\textbf{Access Control}}\\ 
\hline % Observe the space after "Distributed" in the next line
Distributed:,\cite{19paas} &    
& Trusted: & \textbf{Cryptographic }& \textbf{Non-cryptographic} \\ 
\cline{4-5}
    &   &  &  &  \\ 
    &   &  &  & \\
\cline{1-1}\cline{3-4}
Centralized: &    & Semi-trusted: &  &  \\
\cline{2-2}
   &    &  & &  \\ 
   &   &  &  &  \\
\cline{1-1}\cline{3-4}
Cloud: &    & Untrusted: &  & \\
   &   & &   &   \\ 
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Incidentally, instead of six separate `\cite` instructions, you could provide a *single* `\cite` command that takes six arguments:

```
\cite{40crossdomain,51cassandra,53oasis,54huDynamic,79searchengine,19paas}
```

This will allow LaTeX to insert a line break automatically.

---

*Addendum*: The OP has deleted some of the LaTeX code as well as the screeshot I posted.